# tar.xz file is unzipped but the files needs to be joined together

Tags: json, containers, manifest, tar, manifest.json

I have the following folder structure after extracting my tar.xz file.
and inside each folder there is a structure as below:

[image]

how can I join all of them and create the correct environment?

Thanks

[image]